# Entries of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

What is difference between a symmetric matrix over C and hermitian matrix.
Or we have to take entries from R only to define symmetric matrix. 
 What I am understanding is every real symmetric matrix is hermitian but what about complex symmetric matrix?
If I don't use conjugate then complex symmetric matrix need not to be hermitian at all. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2*i&1+i\\
1+i&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is symmetric. But because of the $2*i$ not being real, and the $1+i$ instead of a $1-i$ it is not Hermitian.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a Hermitian matrix is symmetric with respect to the complex inner product. That is,
$$
        \langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,A^*y\rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle,
$$
where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ and where $x,y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Such a matrix has only real eigenvalues because, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then
$$
     (\lambda-\overline{\lambda})\|x\|^2=\langle \lambda x,x\rangle-\langle x,\lambda x\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle-\langle x,Ax\rangle = 0.$$